# JDBC MYSQL Connection without specifying database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sphinx, port

I am using the SphinxQL MySQL client which stores indexes as "tables" but has no real notion of a "database"...One specifies the port (9306 in my case) at which the sphinx mysql instance listens and in theory should be able to communicate as normal.

I have the following test code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Dbtest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:9306",
                         "user","password");
        con.setReadOnly(true);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();    
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from index_turned_table");

        while (res.next()) {
            String stuff1 = res.getString(1);
            String stuff2 = res.getString(2);
            System.out.println("Adding " + stuff1);
            System.out.println("Adding " + stuff2);    
        }

        res.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println (e);
    }
}
```

Upon execution, the code just hangs and does nothing and doesn't print out an exception. What are useful things I can do to figure this out or if any one has direct experience what might be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work with 1.10-beta http://www.olegsmith.com/2010/12/scalalift-sphinxql.html
and not work with 2.0.1-beta. Use mysql-connector-java 5.1.15.

Comment: Thanks oleg..unfortunately I need to use 2.01 beta...any idea why this fix doesn't work for 2.01?...do youhave any suggestions as to where to look or what to try?

Comment: I do not know why it does not work. Probably been modified implementation of the mysql protocol in sphinx. Note that the mysql console tool (mysql --host localhost --port 9306) is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your SphinxQL instance is listening on port 9306. Your MySQL is listening on some other port, likely on the default 3306. You can use MySQL JDBC driver to connect to MySQL, but you cannot use it to connect to SphinxQL. It just doesn't understand JDBC driver communication protocol.

Comment: SphinxQL does not understand the JDBC driver protocol? any sources?

Comment: I guess I was wrong. Looks like there's a possibility to talk via MySQL JDBC driver to SphinxQL, but you might have to solve a bunch of technical issues. There's an answer from @olegsmith but you better be a good Russian reader - Google translation on that article is atrocious! Another post I found: http://kudzia.eu/b/2011/05/mysql-connectorj-5-1-16-sphinxql-0-9-9-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception/