# SQL Unknown Database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

So, I'm trying to create an SQL database in Java. This method has worked in my previous programs, but I just want to make sure it's right. I'm getting an "unknown database" error, which seems odd, since I'm creating the database.

Here's my Java code:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + "(itemid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, amount INTEGER, currprice INTEGER, pricefloor INTEGER, priceceiling INTEGER, currbought INTEGER, pricechange INTEGER, dynamicpricing BOOLEAN);";
String sql2 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + databaseName + ";";
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate(sql2);
statement.executeUpdate("USE " + databaseName + ";");
statement.executeUpdate(sql);
statement.close();
```

Of course, it's all surrounded in a try/catch statement. I catch a stacktrace if there's an error. I'm using MySQL, and my url, username, and password are all correct (triple-checked them!).

Comment: Where exactly you are getting the exception?

Comment: I believe it cannot connect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about any mistake related to `Java`  but remove the `;` from your below code statement

```
statement.executeUpdate("USE " + databaseName + ";");
```

It should be

```
statement.executeUpdate("USE " + databaseName);
```

See [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/creating-database.html) for more information

Comment: Thanks, I've removed that. Didn't fix the issue, but it's definitely good to have correct syntax.

Comment: Are you certain that your `create database` is getting executed successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I think that here you are using the dbname and doesn't exist yet?

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

Use

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://ip/"
```

whitout the dbname

Comment: Hm, this is true - however now I'm getting a "No Database Selected" error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to provide url and database in connection string itself. From this - [JDBC MYSQL Connection without specifying database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371643/jdbc-mysql-connection-without-specifying-database) - maybe your version of mysql jdbc doesn't support connecting to mysql without specifying database.

You should try something like -

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://ip:port/dbname"
```